# Write back through the callback attached to IOLoop in Tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, callback, tornado, python-asyncio

There is a tricky post handler, sometimes it can take a lots of time (depending on a input values), sometimes not.

What I want is to write back whenever 1 second passes, dynamically allocating the response.

```
def post():
    def callback():
        self.write('too-late')
        self.finish()

    timeout_obj = IOLoop.current().add_timeout(
        dt.timedelta(seconds=1),
        callback,
    )

    # some asynchronous operations

    if not self.request.connection.stream.closed():
        self.write('here is your response')
        self.finish()
        IOLoop.current().remove_timeout(timeout_obj)
```

Turns out I can't do much from within `callback`.

Even raising an exception is suppressed by the inner context and won't be passed through the `post` method.

Any other ways to achieve the goal?

Thank you.

**UPD 2020-05-15**:
I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251682/tornado-with-timeout-correct-usage)

Thanks @ionut-ticus, using `with_timeout()` is much more convenient.

After some tries, I think I came really close to what i'm looking for:

```
def wait(fn):
    @gen.coroutine
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrap(*args):
        try:
            result = yield gen.with_timeout(
                    dt.timedelta(seconds=20),
                    IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, fn, *args),
            )
            raise gen.Return(result)
        except gen.TimeoutError:
            logging.error('### TOO LONG')
            raise gen.Return('Next time, bro')
    return wrap


@wait
def blocking_func(item):
    time.sleep(30)
    # this is not a Subprocess.
    # It is a file IO and DB
    return 'we are done here'
```

1. Still not sure, should `wait()` decorator being wrapped in a
   **coroutine**?
2. Some times in a chain of calls of a `blocking_func()`, there can
   be another **ThreadPoolExecutor**. I have a concern, would this work
   without making "mine" one global, and passing to the
   *Tornado*'s `run_in_executor()`?

Tornado: v5.1.1

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to let the client (browser) know their request is still in progress while the async task(s) are running; you should be able to do that using a `PeriodicCallback` that calls `self.write`.

Comment: No, I want response to be patched determine operation timeout. If whole process took 5 seconds - return "not ready". If it took only 1 seconds - respond with "result". It's kinda race - who compute first, but don't take too long.

Comment: Use [tornado.gen.with_timeout](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.with_timeout).

Comment: Could you provide an example code please? I did not find how to catch exception appropriately.

Comment: Example code provided.

Comment: 1) Should wait() decorator be wrapped in a coroutine? -- No, this is already a coroutine, since you put gen.coroutine at line 2. Since it is a coroutine, you need to yield it where ever you use it.

Comment: 2) Since the executor provides the ability to call blocking functions from async, you should not use executor within a blocking function. You can call the blocking function directly or move the logic around so there's an upper level async function which calls blocking_func1 in an executor then later the blocking_func2 in executor.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I call `blocking_func` from async `get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of usage of `tornado.gen.with_timeout`. Keep in mind the task needs to be async or else the IOLoop will be blocked and won't be able to process the timeout:

```py
@gen.coroutine
def async_task():
    # some async code

@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
    try:
        task = self.async_task()
        result = yield gen.with_timeout(delta, task)
        self.write("success")
    except gen.TimeoutError:
        self.write("timeout")
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding about [gen.with_timeout()](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.with_timeout) and about blocking calls. I've made up editing my code to handle blocking calls too.

Comment: This doesn't work. The with_timeout does not stop the task. See the python code showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ustdh3ow/

Comment: The `async_task` needs to be **async** as noted above; try to replace `commands.getstatusoutput("sleep 5")` with `yield tornado.gen.sleep(5)`. Also, the commands module has been deprecated for a while now ...

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise to use https://github.com/aio-libs/async-timeout:

```
import asyncio
import async_timeout

def post():
    try:
        async with async_timeout.timeout(1):
            # some asynchronous operations

            if not self.request.connection.stream.closed():
                self.write('here is your response')
                self.finish()
                IOLoop.current().remove_timeout(timeout_obj)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        self.write('too-late')
        self.finish()
```

Comment: I bet `if not self.request.connection.stream.closed()` condition isn't necessary, because we are going to control it in except clause.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But this is conceptually the same piece of code, just using another abstraction. Is this a right way to do things? Wonder why I can't fine any similar example. I even curious if it would be compatible with the recent `tornado.ioloop` (4.4)

Comment: Yes, it looks almost exactly as your code, that's the point of a modern async code: make it async but try to keep the same structure and readability. This — context manager + exception catching — is a correct, safe and pythonic approach. But it would only work with tornado 5+, so the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61565928/7324965) would be more applicable, yet a little less readable.

Comment: Actually the first code (without run_in_executor) works in Tornado v4.5.3. Now I have to update to Tornado v5.1.1. Sorry for not accepting your answer as the solution - we use Python 2.7 with no AscynIO. But you answer helpful too.